# Одни куки сессии для разных поддоменов

Tags: php

Сайт разделён на поддомены:

domain.ru

pod1.domain.ru

pod2.domain.ru

Как сделать так, чтобы, авторизовавшись на одном домене, авторизация засчитывалась и на всех других?

Делал так, не работает:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.domain.ru');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решилась проблема так

```
session_set_cookie_params(7200, "/", ".site.com", false, false);
```